# Conduct paired t-test for data in one column

Tags: r, reshape, spread, t-test

I am trying to conduct paired t-tests for variables in one column

Here is an example of my data:

```
datexample <- data.frame(
  "time" = c("before","after"), 
  "site" = c("A","B","B","A","A","B","B","A"), 
  "valueA" = c("13","-10", "-5", "18","-14","12", "-17", "19"), 
  "valueB" = c("-3","20", "15", "-16","12","15", "-11", "14")
)
```

Which has an output like this:

```
time    site  valueA valueB
before    A     13     -3
after     B    -10     20
before    B     -5     15
after     A     18    -16
```

I am trying to do four paired t-tests to examine:

1. T-test to determine if there is a difference in valueA between time (before vs after) **at site A**
2. T-test to determine if there is a difference in valueB between time (before vs after) **at site A**
3. T-test to determine if there is a difference in valueA between time (before vs after) **at site B**
4. T-test to determine if there is a difference in valueB between time (before vs after) **at site B**

In order to run the t-test, I need to re-arrange my data so that before and after are each column (instead of being within the time column).

I have tried looking at [other examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52461376/how-to-perform-a-paired-t-test-in-r-when-all-the-values-are-in-one-column), like this:

```
dat_wide <- reshape(datexample, idvar = "time", timevar = "site", direction = "wide")
dat_wide
```

But I end up with a dataset that has only two rows and many columns:

```
time   valueA.A valueB.A valueA.B valueB.B
before       13       -3       -5       15
after        18      -16      -10       20
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are not enough observations for t test.  Do you need chisquare test

Comment: Sorry, I have more observations. I will edit my question.

Comment: I updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to do the `t.test` on the 'value' columns for each 'site', then after grouping by 'site', select the columns of interest in `summarise_at`, and do the `t.test` by subsetting the  values where the 'time' is 'before'/'after'

```
library(dplyr)
datexample %>%
    type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
    group_by(site) %>% 
    summarise_at(vars(starts_with('value')), ~ 
       t.test(.[time == 'before'], .[time == 'after'])$p.value)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  site  valueA valueB
#  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 A      0.393  0.784
#2 B      0.464  0.439
```

Comment: When I run this on my larger dataset, I get the error message: "Error in time == "before" : 
  comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types"

Comment: @jl748795  That could be an issue on your data part i.e. having `NA` or other values and not the code

Comment: I went through my dataset and I have no NA values, just the two sites, two time categories, and negative and positive numbers for the values.

Comment: @jl748795  can you please update your post with a small example that shows the issue i.e. with `dput`